# Create multiple shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a Wordpress Plugin that creates shortcodes. I want to load those shortcodes with an given name via my plugin.

like this `[name]`

But when I save my shortcode the shortcode is generated but not saved

What am I doing wrong.

**This is my form**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Naam:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="naam" type="text" placeholder="Geef hier een unieke naam op" required/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Site URL:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="url" type="text" placeholder="Site URL" required/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Breedte:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="breedte" type="text" placeholder="Breedte in pixels" required/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Bevestig:
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php submit_button('Upload') ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**On post:**

```
if(isset($_POST['naam'])) {
    $naam = $_POST['naam'];
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $breedte = $_POST['breedte'];
    createShortcode($naam, $url, $breedte);
    add_shortcode($naam, 'createShortcode');
}
```

**Create shortcode function**

```
function createShortcode($naam, $url, $breedte){
    echo 'Naam: ' . $naam . ' ';
    echo 'URL: ' . $url . ' ';
    echo 'Breedte: ' . $breedte . ' ';
}
```

Comment: to store it you must make `return` instead of direct printing

Comment: Makes no sense.. Nothing changed

Comment: if this doesn't make sense, you should avoid questioning, if solution annoys you.. @Kempers

Comment: I've changed it like you told, but nothing changed.

Comment: Makes no sense would be a wrong thing, for answering it.

Comment: I mean "nothing changed"

Comment: @ameenulla0007 your solution is not even a solution. The only difference between `return` and `echo` in shortcode handler is that return will actually output stuff where shortcode was used, while echo will be in the beginning of say post. Don't be so arrogant when you don't really know what you're talking about.

Comment: @IgorYavych i'm not arrogant at all, and nothing such with your purpose too, you don't have any rights to say me arrogant, better be moderate, and do as of community does.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding how `add_shortcode` works. It will only be added on form submit and that'd be the only place where it would work if short code was called after `add_shortcode`. `add_shortcode` works kind of like `add_action` and the actual shortcode on the page kind of works like `do_action`, i.e. triggers a hook supplied to `add_shortcode`. It's not saved anywhere. Also, the function you've passed to `add_shortcode` is incorrect.

Comment: @ThijsKempers well, one option would be to save data you need in the database, then on say `plugins_loaded` hook, run a function which will get your saved data from the DB and run `add_shortcode` for each instance of your saved shortcode.

Comment: That would be one hell of a code wouldn't it? Don't really know how to start or even how to do it...

Comment: @ThijsKempers no, not really. Either way, I gave you an idea. No one is going to write this for you. You can try to do it and if you have troubles, you can come back and ask specific question about said trouble

Comment: And if I want just 1 shortcode, can I do it then like the way above?

Comment: @ThijsKempers still no since the problem I've described to you remains